# Could have vs would have

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

**could have** vs **would have**

I know *could* means indicating a possibility or ability, and *would* means the past of will or something about that is uncertain.

Which of the following is correct?

> If you had told me, I **would** have used the other route.
>   If you had told me, I **could** have used the other route.

Both of the above sound correct and similar to me.

Are these also possible?

> If you **had told** me, I **would** use the other route.
>   If **you tell** me, I **would** use the other route.

Please clear my confusion.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Please make an effort to observe ordinary rules of punctuation and capitalization. And you can make your question easier for people to read and answer by employing the available formatting options. See [THIS](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/996/32).

Comment: Go back in time where these sentences are turned into present tense. This may give you some hint: *If you tell me, I **will** use the other route.* **and** *If you tell me, I **can** use the other route.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If you had told me, I **would** have used the other route.
>   If you had told me, I **could** have used the other route.

*Would* here denotes a **certain** consequence of the unreal condition: no question about it, I *would* have used the other route.

*Could* denotes a **possible** consequence of the unreal condition: if you had told me, I might still have taken this route but I would have had the choice of taking the other route.

> If you **had told**<sup>Past Irrealis</sup> me, I **would**<sup>Present Irrealis</sup> use the other route.
>   If **you tell**<sup>Present Realis</sup> me, I **would**<sup>Present Irrealis</sup> use the other route.

These are not quite impossible, but the circumstances under which either would be acceptable are very unlikely to arise. Ordinarily these forms would be understood as having the tense/mode significances I have noted in superscript, and in most cases the two verbs, the one in the *IF* clause and the one in the *THEN* clause, should have the same tense and mode.<sup>†</sup>

---

<sup>†</sup> This is not always the case in conditional clauses involving logical *inference*; but I do not think either of these sentences can be read as inferential.

Comment: What about "I **might have used** the other route."? Is it the same as "I **could have used** the other route."?

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng Yes.

Comment: Besides, doesn't **"could have used"** signal the ability? Here it should be equivalent to **"would have been able to use"**, which I think has nothing to do with a possible consequence as "might have used" signals.

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng But in practical terms they amount to the same thing: because you failed to inform me, my 'capability' remained merely potential, I had no reason to actualize it. *Can* implicates *do* - in fact, simple past *could* usually means *did*: "I found I could do anything I put my mind to.* Irrealis *could* implicates *did not*.